# Reflecting Oracle DB with SQLalchemy, doesn't reflect the columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm connecting the Oracle DB, that I do not control. Since I have to define the custom schema before I can access the tables, automapping the DB isn't working for me. Also for some reason sqlalchemy or oracle doesn't know how to autoincrement id's, therefore my only solution is to reflect the tables, I think. SQLalchemy can find the tables, but the problem is that when I try to do queries, it complains that `AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'column_a'`, and when I print all the columns it clearly has them. `print([c.name for c in reflected_table_a.columns])` it prints: ['id', 'column_a', ...]

```
# connecting the DB
engine = create_engine("oracle+cx_oracle://" +str(connection_string))

# reflecting tables
Base = declarative_base()

reflected_table_a = Table('TABLE_A',
    Base.metadata,
    # With this line I'm also getting the Invalid Identifier error
    #Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    autoload=True,
    autoload_with=engine,
    schema='oracle_stuff'
)

# making the session
session = create_session(bind=engine)

session.query(reflected_table_a).filter(reflected_table_a.column_a == 'foo').all()
# here we are getting the "AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'column_a'" error

#this works just fine
session.query(reflected_table_a).all()
# gets all the rows
```

So it almost works but it doesn't, running out of ideas of how to fix this. Column names and table names are matching to their counter parts in the DB.

Comment: For a `Table`, you use `.c` to access columns: `reflected_table_a.c.column_a`